# Edit previous data using entityframe work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Error Message:

> Attaching an entity of type `'ReadingDataStoringToLocation.destinationroute'` failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value"

Here is my code.

```cs
DRoutes.airportid = Convert.ToInt32(route.SelectSingleNode("airportid").FirstChild.InnerText);

DRoutes.resortid = Convert.ToInt32(route.SelectSingleNode("resortid").FirstChild.InnerText);

DRoutes.name = route.SelectSingleNode("resortname").FirstChild.InnerText;                                    

DRoutes.airportname = route.SelectSingleNode("airportname").FirstChild.InnerText;

DRoutes.id = data.id;

Db.Entry(DRoutes).State = EntityState.Modified;

Db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Like the Message said, it seems that you want to modify a item in your database to an item, which has same values in the primary as another item in your database. That shouldn't work, because primary keys must be unique.

Comment: yeah but i want update previous data which is in database , can u tell me that code

Answer (score 0):

It seems this line is which gives you the error message... remove it, maybe?

```
DRoutes.id = data.id;
```